# Failure creating Angular 2 observable while executing GET request on local API

Tags: angular, observable

Using an HttpClient to send a GET request to an API running locally; I'm trying to make a proof of concept by hardcoding for the time being, and although I won't clutter this with API code, it correctly returns this JSON in Postman:

```
{
"id": 123456789,
"firstName": "Bill"
}
```

So, the component method I'm working with at the moment does some logging, then sends the fields of the component to my service; it's anchored to the submit button on my login form:

```
submitLoginForm(){
  console.log("Username: " + this.username + ", Password: " + 
    this.password);
  this.loginService.getUser(this.username, this.password);
  console.log("End");
}
```

Then I make a call to the service method, which creates an observable - or attempts to - from the results of the GET request:

```
getUser(): Observable<User> {
  if (this.user) {
    return Observable.from([this.user]);
  } else {
    console.log('Starting observable');
    let observable = Observable.create(observer => {
      this.http.get('localhost:8080/login?username=RainyDayMatt&password=W@nder3r27').subscribe((resp) => {
        console.log('GET success');
        console.log(resp.json);
        this.user = resp.json();
        observer.next(this.user);
        observer.complete();
      },
        (err) => {
          console.log('GET failure');
          console.log(err);
          observer.next(false);
          observer.complete();
        });
    });
    console.log('Ending observable');
    return observable;
  }
}
```

But I only get the attached logging; there's obviously an invisible failure in the observable creation block. I just can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

[image: Logging]

Answer (score 0):

The new HttpClient in `@angular/common/http` automatically parses JSON responses (the old one didn't). You should be able to do `console.log(resp);`. I think that's where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was unable to access the full body of the error because of a CORS issue; I added a cross-origin allowance on the API in order to diagnose the error more fully. I got the full error, which informed me that the operation I was attempting wasn't supported except for HTTP, HTTPS, and a few other protocols.

Sure enough, adding "http://" to the GET endpoint fixed it right up.